# Error using Parse - "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ParseClientConfiguration", referenced from:

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, buddy.com

I am getting two errors after adding Parse in my Project:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ParseClientConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Steps I followed are as follows:

1. Downloaded Parse iOS SDK from
   https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/releases
2. Added Parse iOS SDK manually in Project
3. Added #import  in AppDelegate.m

and then added the code below in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
[Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
   configuration.applicationId = @"YOUR_APP_ID";
   configuration.clientKey = @"YOUR_APP_CLIENT_KEY";
   configuration.server = @"http://localhost:1337/parse";
}]];
```

Note: I did not add Bolts.Framework because when I install FBSDKCoreKit via Pod, Bolts is added as a dependency.

Comment: Please use google to search the issues before open a new question. Here is issue [Undefined symbols for architecture](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/477)

Comment: why not add the SDK via pod too?

Comment: Installing Parse via Pod also installs Bolts that conflicts with the Bolts installed as a dependency of FBSDKCoreKit.

Comment: I am not getting the warnings about deployment target and I also tried installing via Pod as I have mentioned in the comment above. But it did not work. Thanks for your suggestion but it is not answer of my question. @Nazir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by installing Parse SDK via pod and adding FBSDKCoreKit manually (but did not add Bolts framework). Parse and FBSDKCoreKit both require Bolts but different versions. I believe that FBSDKCoreKit installs older version of Bolts while Parse needs newer version and that was the issue.